Unbound module error in dune project even with library specified in build config
let read_file path =
  In_channel.with_open_bin path In_channel.input_all

let solve input = input

let () =
  read_file "input.txt"
  |> solve
  |> print_endline


I am currently trying to run this code but keep running into unbound module In_channel error, I referred to similar threads, it seemed like the solution was to create a local switch and I installed core/bench/utop locally , I also added core as part of build config for the executable. Still it says unbound module. The current status of the folder is below, /dune does call core under libraries. The code is part of main.ml
I am using emacs, I dont know if that matters.

Thanks in advance.

I presume solve has some as of yet unimplemented purpose.

Minor style note: you can write In_channel.(with_open_bin path input_all)

The In_channel module was added to the standard library in OCaml 4.14 . You are probably using an older version of OCaml. You can upgrade to the latest stable version with
opam switch create 5.2.1


It still says the same, currently my env variable is OPAMSWITCH = 5.2.1

Did you check that ocamlopt -v print the expected version? Did you build your code once locally (to initialize the LSP)? Your code snippet compiles without issue for me (even if you might want to remove the dependency on the core library).
